# Jasmine angularjs - spying on angular-local-storage methods called when controller is initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-local-storage

Similar question to: [Jasmine angularjs - spying on a method that is called when controller is initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840097/jasmine-angularjs-spying-on-a-method-that-is-called-when-controller-is-initial)

In my controller I use the angular-local-storage package to provide a localStorageService through injection.

in my unit tests I want to make sure the data is retrieved from the service, so I spy on the "get" and "add" methods and mock them (.andCallFake).

this works fine with all the methods that are called through $scope.$watch - as long as I force a $digest. but for the method that is called on the controller initialization, it does not seem to work. **Can anyone advise why this doesn't work?**

app>Main.js

```
angular.module('angularTodoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','localStorageService',function ($scope, localStorageService) {

    var todosInStore =  localStorageService.get('todos');
    $scope.todos = todosInStore && todosInStore.split('\n') || [];
    //$scope.todos = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

    $scope.$watch('todos', function(){
      localStorageService.add('todos', $scope.todos.join('\n'));
    },true);

    $scope.addTodo  = function() {
      $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
      $scope.todo = '';
    };

    $scope.removeTodo = function(index) {
      $scope.todos.splice(index,1);
    };
  }]);
```

test>Main.js

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('angularTodoApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope,
    localStorageService,
    store = [];

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _localStorageService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    localStorageService = _localStorageService_;
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      localStorageService: _localStorageService_
    });

    //mock localStorageService get/add
    spyOn(localStorageService,'get').andCallFake(function(key){
      return store[key];
    });
    spyOn(localStorageService,'add').andCallFake(function(key, val){
      store[key] = val;
    });
  }));

  it('should retrieve "todos" from the store and assign to scope', function () {
    expect(localStorageService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('todos');
    expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(0);
  });

  it('should add items to the list and update the store for key = "todos"', function () {
    scope.todo = 'Test 1';
    scope.addTodo();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(localStorageService.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('todos', jasmine.any(String));
    expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(1);
  });
```

all tests pass except the one in the constructor:

```
expect(localStorageService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('todos');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the controller is initialised at the point you call `$controller`, which in your example is *before* you're created the spies via `spyOn`. The solution for your example is to move the call to `$controller` to *after* the calls to `spyOn`.

For longer test suites, to keep things DRY, you might have to put the call to `$controller` in a separate function, that you can then call after you have mocked up any required services.

Comment: yeah, I just realized when I woke up. God it's never good to stay up late and try to figure it out! Thanks! Accepted, upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Updated test suite, make sure mocks are in place **before** calling controller constructor:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('angularTodoApp'));

  var MainCtrl,
    scope,
    localStorageService,
    store;

  // Initialize the controller and mocks
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _localStorageService_) {
    store = []; //clear the store before each test
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    localStorageService = _localStorageService_;

    //mock localStorageService get/add
    spyOn(localStorageService,'get').andCallFake(function(key){
      return store[key];
    });
    spyOn(localStorageService,'add').andCallFake(function(key, val){
      store[key] = val;
    });

    //Instantiate controller to test
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      localStorageService: localStorageService
    });
  }));

  it('should retrieve "todos" from the store and assign to scope', function () {
    expect(localStorageService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('todos');
    expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(0);
  });

  it('should add items to the list and update the store for key = "todos"', function () {
    scope.todo = 'Test 1';
    scope.addTodo();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(localStorageService.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('todos', jasmine.any(String));
    expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('should remove items to the list and update the store', function() {
    scope.todo = 'Test 1';
    scope.addTodo();
    scope.$digest();
    //reset call count
    localStorageService.add.reset();

    scope.removeTodo(0);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(localStorageService.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith('todos', jasmine.any(String));
    expect(scope.todos.length).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: I made exact changes like in your code, and now appears error

 `Controller: MainCtrl should add items to the list and update the store for key = "todos" FAILED
            [native code]
        })> ] but it was never called.
        Error: Expected spy add to have been called with [ 'todos', <jasmine.any(function String() { 
            at D:/js-app/apps/mytodo/test/spec/controllers/main.js:41`
Do you have any ideas why it could be?

Comment: could you put your code in a gist? I've been busy with Docker & Infrastructure and handed the Angular coding to a colleague, so apart from an overview perspective I haven't worked with it for almost a year.... - but I can try to help.

Comment: Ok, that you for your help offer, i already find an answer. I found somewhere, that i should add timeout, 'cause it seems that there is some time before service mock was emuated. Now it works well

Comment: if you post your code as answer, I'll accept it as the answer for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

You also need to include the LocalStorageModule in your beforeEach() call for loading the module in test.js file.

```
beforeEach(module('angularTodoApp', 'LocalStorageModule'));
```

Also, don't forget to update your karma.conf.js file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    // ...
    files: [
        '/path/to/angular.min.js',
        '/path/to/angular-mocks.js',
        '/path/to/angular-local-storage.js',
        'Main/test.js',
        'Main/app.js'
    ],
    //...
```

I just stumbled on the same problem, this did the trick for me.

Finally, you also need to modify the `spyOn(...).andCallFake(...)` call if you're using Jasmine 2.4 with `spyOn(...).and.callFake(...)`

The method given in the previous answers is not working in Jasmine 2.4 (not tested in previous versions though).